# Как сделать запись в бд вместо textarea замена на option select?

Tags: php, база-данных, css3, html5

```
<td>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="comment[]" rows="1"><?php echo $row['teacher_comment'];?></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="answer_id[]" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
</td>
```

Вот что имеется на данный момент: это коммент, в который вписывается значение и хранится в нем после сохранения.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать это корректно, чтобы это был выпадающий список options select из значений "true/false".
Если не трудно, то сможете показать наглядно на коде)
Заранее прекрайне благодарен!

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос. У Вас есть поле `textarea`, куда вписывается комментарий учителя. И Есть поле с `id` этой записи. Как именно, и какое именно из полей Вы хотите заменить на `select`? Чтобы вместо чего были значения `true` или `false`?

Comment: @Denis640Kb , Да, конечно. Вопрос весь в замене textatea, в котором хранится комментарий учителя, на select, чтобы вместо комментария, учитель мог просто выбрать true или false (аналог сдал/не сдал). Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаем поле `select` в котором указываем проверку. 
Если данные `$row['teacher_comment']` равны `True`, то делаем соответствующее поле `option` выбранным.
Тоже самое со вторым полем.
И получаем данные выбранного поля `select` по имени.

```php
<?php
$row['teacher_comment'] = ""; // Здесь получаем значение поля, либо из сессии, из БД или другими способами.
?>
<form method="post" action="">
    <select id="sel" name="sel">
        <option></option>
        <option value="True" <?php if ($row['teacher_comment'] == "True"){ echo 'selected';}?>>Сдал</option>
        <option value="False" <?php if ($row['teacher_comment'] == "False"){ echo 'selected';}?>>Не сдал</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="answer_id[]" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
    <button name="but" formmethod="post">Сохранить</button>
</form>

<?php
// Добавляем форму для отправки данных.
// Если необходимо обрабатывать другим файлом, то указываем этот файл в action

if(isset($_POST['sel'])){ // Если Поле с именем sel выбрано, то получаем данные.
    $row['teacher_comment'] = $_POST['sel'];
} else { // Если данные не введены, то проставляем пустое значение.
    $row['teacher_comment'] = "";
}
```